# What is the fastest way to get the numpy values from a column slice of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Too often I've tried to decide how to get the `numpy` array associated with several but not all columns in a `pandas` dataframe.

So I'm asking, what is the most efficient way to get the array of values associated with several but not all columns in a dataframe?

***Example***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10).reshape(-1, 5), columns=list('ABCDE'))
print(df)

   A  B  C  D  E
0  0  1  2  3  4
1  5  6  7  8  9
```

What is fastest way to get

```
df[['B', 'D']].values

array([[1, 3],
       [6, 8]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach by getting the column integer indices with `np.searchsorted` against the given string indices -

```
def linear_index(df, cols):    
    r,c = df.columns.levels
    d0 = np.array([i[0] for i in cols])
    d1 = np.array([i[1] for i in cols])    

    # Skip getting the argsorts if column names are already sorted
    r_sidx = r.argsort()
    c_sidx = c.argsort()

    return np.searchsorted(r,d0,sorter = r_sidx)*len(c) + \
                        np.searchsorted(c,d1, sorter=c_sidx)

def searchsorted_loc(df, cols):
    return df.values[:, linear_index(df, cols)]
```

This works for `multi-index` dataframes. It would simplify when working with one level dataframes.

Comment: `searchsorted_loc` is of similar speed as others.  `linear_index` is far too quick... so I compared it and doesn't seem to produce the correct results.  I can look into why later.  I'll add to analysis when I figure out why.

Comment: @piRSquared Any luck on figuring out the issue? Or some minimal sample on which that issue could be reproduced?

Comment: I forgot about this question:-). Now I have it to look forward to

Answer (score 2):

I thought of these methods... I welcome more to include in the analysis

***conclusions***
For a small number of columns, it appears that finding the column locations and slicing with integers is pretty effective.  But for large arrays and large number of columns, `as_matrix` is very good (as expected).

```
from timeit import timeit
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from string import ascii_uppercase as up


def slc_df_2val(df, cols):
    return df[cols].values

def as_matrix(df, cols):
    return df.as_matrix(cols)

def hstack_per_col(df, cols):
    return np.hstack([df[c].values[:, None] for c in cols])

def stack_per_col_T(df, cols):
    return np.stack([df[c].values for c in cols]).reshape(-1, len(cols))

def get_loc_slc_array(df, cols):
    a = [df.columns.get_loc(c) for c in cols]
    return df.values[:, a]
```

Then I conduct the following test

```
mcol = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([list(up[:10]), list(up[-10:])])

sizes = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [[10, 100, 1000, 10000], [1, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40]],
    names=['n', 'm'])

methods = pd.Index(
    'slc_df_2val as_matrix hstack_per_col stack_per_col_T get_loc_slc_array'.split(),
    name='method')

results = pd.DataFrame(index=sizes, columns=methods)

np.random.seed([3,1415])
for n in sizes.levels[0]:
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(n * 100).reshape(-1, 100), columns=mcol)
    for m in sizes.levels[1]:
        cols = np.random.choice(mcol, m, replace=False)
        for f in methods:
            stmt = '{}(df, cols)'.format(f)
            setup = 'from __main__ import {}, df, cols'.format(f)
            tvalue = timeit(stmt, setup, number=500)
            results.set_value((n, m), f, tvalue)
```

And plot the `results` from a perspective of what happens for each method as the number of columns we are extracting increases.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(8, 6))
for i, n in enumerate(sizes.levels[0]):
    ax = axes[i // 2, i % 2]
    results.xs(n).plot(lw=2, ax=ax, title='size {}'.format(n))
    ax.legend().remove()

axes[-1, -1].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.7, 2.4), fontsize=10)

fig.suptitle('Num Columns Perspective', fontsize=10)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(top=.9)
```

[image]

Then from the perspective of growing array length

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 2, figsize=(8, 9))
for i, m in enumerate(sizes.levels[1]):
    ax = axes[i // 2, i % 2]
    results.xs(m, level=1).plot(lw=2, ax=ax, title='num cols {}'.format(m), rot=45)
    ax.legend().remove()

axes[-1, -1].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.7, 4.1), fontsize=10)

fig.suptitle('Array Length Perspective', fontsize=10)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(top=.9)
```

[image]